# How long can duplicate SQS messages persist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using an SQS queue in my application. To handle duplicates I store a unique id from the queue item in a DynamoDB table. Then for each item I check if it exists first.

How long should I keep these id's in my DynamoDB table? i.e. once an item is processed how long after is it possible for duplicates of that item to arrive from SQS?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the producer of the message how fast the duplicate messages are generated and published to the queue

Comment: The only reason you need to do this is if the sender might insert duplicates into the queue. If you follow the proper process for dealing with SQS messages, the only way you will a duplicate (meaning, downloading the same message ID more than once) is if you don't process it before the visibility timeout (VTO) expires. The proper process flow should be: client downloads message, client does work, client deletes message. If the VTO expires before you can delete it, then SQS will deliver the same message to the client again.

Comment: @howcheng that isn't true of standard queues.  SQS guarantees *at least once* delivery and if an internal error or other situation occurs that leaves SQS uncertain whether a message was delivered, it can be received again by any consumer and will have the same MessageId.  This is rare but theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented time frame as far as I know. It should only be a matter of a few seconds though.

Comment: I am inclined to agree, but if the duplicate were caused by an internal network partition event inside SQS resulting in a split brain condition or a dirty rejoin (let's say the root cause was a transient isolation of one availability zone), it could conceivably be longer... *maybe* up to the message retention period for the queue (default 4 days, max 14) after which any remaining messages automatically fall off the edge of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 modes in SQS - standard queue and FIFO.
Let's assume further that consumers delete handled messages (if you don't have it, then this is what you need the first thing).

FIFO queue doesn't have duplicates delivered. Standard queue may have duplicates. Since you have duplicates, let's go further with standard queue.

Standard queue uses eventual consistency while providing high performance.
**We cannot ask for concrete time when there is no duplicate assuming we use eventually consistent approach.**

If you need strong consistency and concrete numbers, then go with FIFO queue.

Answer (score 0):

Once a message has been removed from the standard queue you can assume that you will not see it again. Therefore, the duplicate threat, in theory, persists until the message has been removed from the queue... either by error, successful completion or manual removal.

That said, if you have a redrive policy set up to retry errored messages after the visibility timeout has expired you probably don't want to treat those retries as duplicates. Therefore you will not only want to store the message's unique id, but its status as well.